# Passing multiple values as function in a single function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In Python, we normally pass arguements in the function when we have to call them multiple times as below:

```
def function_add(a,b):
print(a+b)

function_add(4,5)
function_add(5,7)
function_add(10,4)
function_add(4,6)
```

Do we have a similar way to implement it in VBA too? I tried to implement it but I couldn't make it. Below is my code.

```
Private Sub SearchAndInsertRows()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim search As String
Dim kk As String

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A")
search = ""
Call searchGetKey(search)
Set cell = rng.Find(What:=search, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

If cell Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Not Found"
Else
    kk = ""
    Call searchSetKey(kk)
    cell.Value = kk   
End If
End Sub

Sub searchGetKey(ByRef getKey As String)
    getKey = "a"
End Sub  

Sub searchSetKey(ByRef setKey As String)
    setKey = "b"       
End Sub
```

Sub searchGetKey and searchSetKey modifies one cell but I need to do the same for number of cells. Is there any other ways to do it?

Please fell free to optimize the code wherever necessary.

Thank you very much and much appreciated. :)

Comment: I must confess **I cannot understand what you try accomplishing in your code** and I cannot help you to correct it. I posted an answer with examples regarding the way of using functions or subs in VBA... If you still do not understand what is to be done and explain **in words** what you try doing I will show you how to deal with it. In VBA you use `Let` and `Get` only in classes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function in VBA must return something. Otherwise, you should use a `Sub`:

```
Function function_add(a As Long, b As Long) As Long
   function_add = a + b
End Function

Sub TestFunction()
   MsgBox function_add(3, 5)
End Sub
```

You can use a function without arguments, just returning according to a specific calculation algorithm. For instance:

```
Function tomorrow_Date() As Date
     tomorrow_Date = Date + 1
End Function
```

It can be called as:

```
Sub testTommorrow_Date()
   MsgBox tomorrow_Date
End Sub
```

Or a `Sub` which by default takes arguments `ByRef`, if not specified `ByVal`:

```
Sub Sub_add(a As Long, b As Long, c As Long)
    c = a + b
End Sub
```

And test it as:

```
Sub TestSub_Add()
   Dim c As Long
   Sub_add 3, 2, c
   MsgBox c
End Sub
```

Of course, `a` and `b` may be declared in the testing `Sub` and used like arguments, but I wanted saying that they are not relevant against `c` which was updated after the call...